# Can I re-install Windows using someone else's disc?

Tags: windows-vista, installation

My laptop came pre-installed with Windows Vista and naturally no Windows disc. Is it legal to borrow a friend's retail Vista disc and install Windows using the serial number from the sticker on my laptop? Will this even work?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if you still have a registration available for the license, and if the install media type matches your serial type. You can't use an OEM key on a Retail install for example, but if they match, using someone else's media is fine if you're using your purchased key to install. Microsoft even allows you to purchase their [alternate](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsvista/1033/ordermedia/default.mspx) or [replacement media](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326246), if you provide a product key.

Comment: What does the word, registration, mean in this context and how do I know if I have it available?

Comment: If you bought your own windows disk say from Best Buy, and now want to reinstall because your disk is trashed. You could not use a a Vista disk that say I got with my pc.

Comment: @May, if you haven't used your serial before, you should still have 10 registrations available I believe as stated in the EULA. This also depends on if your friend has a retail install CD or not. The key on your machine is likely OEM.

Answer (score 1):

Before you reinstall Vista with a OEM DVD (the license key from your COA sticker will not work with a reatail disk), you should backup the activation files and product key of your Windows installation.

Here's a tutorial for you:

**[Backup and restore Vista activation and product key](http://www.webtlk.com/2007/12/14/backup-and-restore-vista-activation-and-product-key/)**